# php template add dynamic js and css

Tags: php, html, template-engine

I design my php  products page template like this :

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<?PHP include ('dynamicpage.php'); //load dynamic page request example: adduser.php ?>

</body>
</html>
```

i need to add `.js` and `.css` file in each `dynamicpage.php` like this:

adduser.php :

```
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/formvalidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/formvalidation.min.js"></script> 

<?PHP // code + html ?>
```

addpage.php :

```
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/select2.min.js"></script> 

<?PHP // code + html ?>
```

Now, i need to print daynamic `.js` and `.css` from dynamic page to top of page into `<head></head>` like this:

if i load addpage.php my head template is :

```
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

if i load adduser.php my head template is :

```
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/formvalidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/formvalidation.min.js"></script>
```

how do print `.js` and `.css` using any php function or class?! sorry im new user of `PHP` and not have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the way you have it setup, instead you could set the contents of `dynamicpage.php` as a variable and use that variable in the body. If you setup other variables for the additional CSS and JS files, you could use those too.

Contents of your `dynamicpage.php` could be this:

```
$css = "dynamicpage.css";
$js = "dynamicpage,js";
$content = "<div>blabla</div>";
```

Your index file could look something like this:

```
<?PHP include ('dynamicpage.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/user/admin/templates/css/<?php echo $css; ?>" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="/user/admin/templates/js/<?php echo $js; ?>"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $content; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Highly recommend `require_once()` instead of  `include ()`

Answer (score 0):

Just test the following code and you will get your result:

index.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['a']) || (!isset($_GET['a']) && !isset($_GET['b']))) {
    include ('link1.php');
  } elseif (isset($_GET['b'])) {
    include ('link2.php');
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <?=$links?>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="?a">Link 1</a>
  <a href="?b">Link 2</a>
  <?php page(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

link1.php

```
<?php
  $links = 
    '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />';

  function page() {
?>
  <div>Some HTML code here...</div>
<?php } ?>
```

link2.php

```
<?php
  $links = 
    '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyle.css" />';

  function page() {
?>
  <div>Some other HTML code here...</div>
<?php } ?>
```

save the codes above each one in different file and with the same names as I provided and test them in your local or remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Like I suggeated earlier in another thread 
 to link multiple files put the include in the head of your index file and then you can just add files to include by updating the arrays.make this function in a the include file, Adjust the paths to suit

```
 $stylesheets = array('style.css','prettyPhoto.css','nivo-slider.css');
 $scripts = array('core.js','core.js',
                      'jquery-1.4.1.min.js',
                      'jquery-slidedeck.pack.lite.js',
                      'jquery-prettyPhoto.js',
                      'jquery.nivo.slider.js');
foreach($stylesheets as $styles){
   echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$styles' />";
 }

 foreach($scripts as $script){
   echo "<script src='$script'></script>";
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Dynamic Administration on a Public Hostname (ex: www.example.com)
// Use NO-IP or DYNDNS.ORG for Dynamic Hostname

$conn_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Your Internet Connection
$host_ip = gethostbyname('your.dynamichost.com'); // Points to your Internet Connection Dynamically

if($conn_ip == $host_ip && $username == "Admin"){

    // Do Admin Stuff

}
```